# Finding specific solutions from percentages of subgroups

Tags: statistics

So I have this problem I can't seem to solve, I might be overthinking it, english is not my first language...

The sample size is 1525,

Total all groups: 45% agree, 45% disagree, 10% didn't answer

Group a) 90% agree 6% disagree 4% didn't answer

Group b) 40% agree 45% disagree 15% didn't answer

Group c) 14% agree 81% disagree 5% didn't answer

How many people were in group a?

Thanks in advance.
If the final number is a range (between x&y) please let me know.

Comment: you have $686.25$ people agreeing

Answer (score 1):

Let $a,b,c$ the porportion of the groups. Then you have the following linear equation system.

$$0.9a+0.4b+0.14c=0.45$$

$$0.06a+0.45b+0.81c=0.45$$

$$a+b+c=1$$

The third equation uses the fact that the porportions have to add up to 1.

The solution is $(a,b,c)=(0.229008,0.522901,0.248092)$

The number of people in group a is $0.229008\cdot 1525\approx 349.24$. We have to round off. Thus $a^*=349$

There must be a mistake in the exercise because $0.45\cdot 1525=668.25$. The number people who agree/disagree should be a whole number as well.

Or the porpotions itself have been already rounded. In this case the solution $a^*$ is OK.